# Failed to insert table in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

I do the following, and finally causes the insert to fail:

cnosdb-cli

```
CREATE TENANT tenant_a;
CREATE USER user_a;
ALTER TENANT tenant_a ADD USER user_a AS owner;
```

cnosdb-cli -u user_a -t tenant_a:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_a;
\c db_a
CREATE TABLE air_a (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,pressure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));
INSERT INTO air_a (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES(1666165200290401000, 'XiaoMaiDao', 56, 69, 77);
```

cnosdb_cli:

```
DROP TENANT IF EXISTS tenant_a;
DROP USER IF EXISTS user_a;
CREATE TENANT tenant_a;
CREATE USER user_a;
ALTER TENANT tenant_a ADD USER user_a AS owner;
```

cnosdb-cli -u user_a -t tenant_a:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_a;
\c db_a
CREATE TABLE air_a (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,pressure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));
INSERT INTO air_a (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES(1666165200290401000, 'XiaoMaiDao', 56, 69, 77);
```

Show error:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"020004","error_message":"DataSchemaError: database 'db_a' not found"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This BUG no longer appears.

Maybe it was originally due to a meta synchronization error.

https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/issues/1459